# Google Play Service only works with Android Studio

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

I have a very strange problem with my Android App and the Google Play Services.

With the debug Version of my App everthing works fine. And also when I started the release App over Android Studio on my real device it worked. But when I installed the App from Google PlayStore the Game Services stopped working after about 10 min. And I was not able to sign in again.

Then I uninstall the App from my device and tested it from Andoid Studio again. The first time it didn't work, but after reinstall it via Android Studio the Play Services worked again. Then I tried the App from PlayStore again, and first it worked again, but after a view minutes I had the same problems then before to sign in.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check the [Prepare for Release](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/preparing.html). Did you try using release key instead of debug key?

Comment: Yes i did it all and used release key. When i install the release-apk direct on Phone the Google Play Services works, but when i install my app from Google PlayStore the Services doesn't work.

Thsnks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old post, but probably there are other developers facing that issue. You probably didn't set the fingerprint of your signing certificate of the app in the play store in your API console:
https://developer.android.com/games/pgs/console/setup

Remember, you need to register both, the key of your productive app and your development version. Don't confuse with the key you use for uploading. The released version of your app is not signed with that one, but rather with the certificate displayed in your play console under configure -> app-integrity -> app signing tab